# What's the difference between a solidity contract and an OOP class?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I learned that solidity contracts and OOP (object-oriented programming) classes, such as those in Java, are similar in many aspects. They can have constructors, class methods with public/private usage, and variable declaration/initialization. Also, they can be instantiated.

Those are some similarities and maybe I got something wrong, but I am very eager to know the differences between Solidity contracts and classes in OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are really similar, but not quite the same.  The language is the same in many cases, and i think they were going for that, but there are even more fundamental differences that the fact that solidity contracts can store and send value and have a public address once deployed.

This question was asked before too,  and there were some good answers.
[Is a smart contract analogous to an OOP class?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12596/is-a-smart-contract-analogous-to-an-oop-class?rq=1)